# merge python dictionary keys based on common elements

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, merge, key

Let's say we have a dictionary like this:

```
{0: [2, 8], 1: [8, 4], 3: [5]}
```

Then we encounter a key value pair **2 , 8** . Now, as the value **2** and **8** has already appeared for key **0**, I need to merge the first two keys and create a new dictionary like the following:

```
{0: [2, 8, 4], 3: [5]}
```

I understand that it's possible to do a lot of looping and deleting. I'm really looking for a more pythonish way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *a key value pair 2 , 8* - Where is the key `2` in the result? And what happened to the key `1`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: perhaps because the incoming key was 2, the key that contained the incoming key (in this case, `0`) took precedence?

Comment: i'm sorry, it would key 0, not key 1.

Comment: what if the original dictionary contained `3: [5,8]`?

Comment: as i'm creating the dictionary on the fly, this won't happen. because 3, along with 5 and 8 will be already merged with key 0.

Comment: Im gonna go out on a limb here and say this dictionary is perhaps not the right data structure to use ...

Comment: ya @JoranBeasley , but i'm unsure about the right one. so i'm giving it a try.

Answer (score 2):

your coworkers will hate you later but here

```
>>> d = {0: [2, 8], 1: [8, 4], 3: [5]}
>>> x = ((a,b) for a,b in itertools.combinations(d,2) if a in d and b in d and set(d[a]).intersection(d[b]))
>>> for a,b in x:d[min(a,b)].extend([i for i in d[max(a,b)] if i not in d[min(a,b)]]) or d.pop(max(a,b))
[8, 4]
>>> d
{0: [2, 8, 4], 3: [5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {0: [2, 8], 
     1: [8, 4], 
     3: [5]}

revmap = {}
for k,vals in d.items():
    for v in vals:
        revmap[k] = v

k,v = 2,8
d[revmap[k]].extend([i for i in d[revmap[v]] if i not in d[revmap[k]]])
d.pop(revmap[v])
```